# Can .htaccess 301 redirects work with encoded characters?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url, internationalization

I have an old site with titles in the URL for SEO, but it has URL encoded characters than transliterated Latin characters. Like %20 instead of space character and many other non-Latin characters.  The site is not in English.

I'm moving the site to a new CMS and it transliterates the titles before puttng them into URL bar (which is nice and I'm happy to have).

I'm writing 301 redirects in my *.htaccess* and they work if all characters of the title are in Latin (the same in both side).

How can I redirect the old encoded URLs to the new transliterated URLS using .htaccess?

Comment: Minor point... "html entities ... Like %20" - this is a URL (or percent) encoded character, not an HTML entity. HTML entities start `&` (ampersand). `RewriteRule` matches against the %-decoded characters. Have you tried saving your .htaccess file in UTF-8 and typing the non-latin characters directly?

Answer (score 2):

It should just work fine provided that the URL is enclosed in double-quotations.

For example, if you have:

- Old URL: `http://www.example.com/folder%20name/page%20name.html`
- New URL: `http://www.example.com/folder/page`

You can write:

```
Redirect 301 "/folder/page%20name.html" http://www.example.com/folder/page
```

Comment: For me, adding quotes and decoding the percent signs worked.  E.g. `"/folder/page name.html"`